# Putting Markers on a Map

Tags: plot, maps

I am trying to create a map of the United States that illustrates the following data:

- how competitive a state's senate election was in the year 2006
- whether a state had a female candidate running for the Senate that year.

I have no problem creating a map that has a competition scale (I use color to indicate this--i.e. more competitive states appear in a darker color than less competitive states.).  What I would like to do in addition to this is to put a marker or flag of some sort on the states that had a female candidate.

The below code is what I'm using to create my competition map, but **I'm having a hard time figuring out how to add to it to create these markers**.

The code is below.  The variable I would like to incorporate to create the markers is a binary (`1` if the state had a female candidate; `0` otherwise).  One more note: the data that I'm using for this is Total--Total is comprised of all_states (which I created from using the data built into the maps package and data containing information about candidate gender and competition.

```
all_states <- map_data("state")

Total <- merge(all_states, new.data2, by="region")

p <- ggplot()

p <- p + geom_polygon(data=Total, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group, fill=Total$comp_scale),colour="cyan"
) + scale_fill_continuous(low = "blue", high = "darkblue", guide="colorbar")  

P1 <- p + theme_bw()  + labs(fill = "Competition"
                             ,title = "Level of Competition: 2006 Senate Races", x="", y="")
comp2006 <- P1 + scale_y_continuous(breaks=c()) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c()) + theme(panel.border =  element_blank())
```

comp2006

Answer (score 0):

for this im not getting which language you are using for the map creation , for this can use like this code as reference to use markers or reply  me with a language so that i can help you out  this is javascrpit code  or as refernce you can use this link
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

function initialize() {

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);

var mapOptions = {

zoom: 4,

center: myLatlng

}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

position: myLatlng,

map: map,

title: 'Hello World!'

});

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);